# hot module replacement is disabled

Tags: node.js, webpack

I’m having below issue when running build function using web pack, can you please have a look? npm build、 delete node_modules、update node.js version. Please help me.

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var OpenBrowserPlugin = require('open-browser-webpack-plugin');
var node_modules = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');
var pathToReact = path.resolve(node_modules, 'react/react');
var pathToReactDOM = path.resolve(node_modules, 'react-dom/index')

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  devServer: {
    /*headers: {
       'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
       'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
     },*/
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
    inline: true,
    contentBase: './webapp/build',
    progress: true,
    port: 8000,
    proxy: {
     '\*': {
         //target: 'http://10.10.2.124:8082',
         target: 'http://10.10.1.89:8080',
       secure: false
     }
    } 
  },
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8000',
    'webpack/hot/dev-server',
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'react/main.js')
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/webapp/build',
    publicPath: '/build',
    filename: './bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: "[id].bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
    }, {
        test: /\.js[x]?$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'react'),
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel-loader?cacheDirectory'],
        noParse: [pathToReact, pathToReactDOM]
    }, {
      test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
      loader: 'url-loader'
    }, {
      test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?.*$|$)/,
      loader: 'url'
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new OpenBrowserPlugin({
      url: 'http://localhost:8000/dev/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "***",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "admin",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server react/main.js --devtool eval --progress --hot --inline --colors --content-base webapp/build",
    "deploy": "set NODE_ENV=production && webpack --config webpack.production.config.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "1.1.0",
    "babel-runtime": "6.x",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^0.4.0",
    "echarts": "^3.4.0",
    "react": "0.14.x",
    "react-dom": "0.14.x",
    "reflux": "^0.4.1",
    "reqwest": "^2.0.5",
    "webpack-parallel-uglify-plugin": "^0.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "animate.css": "^3.5.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.10.4",
    "babel-eslint": "6.x",
    "babel-loader": "6.x",
    "babel-plugin-antd": "^0.4.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-simple-amd": "^0.3.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "6.x",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.x",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.x",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "6.x",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "2.x",
    "css-loader": "~0.23.0",
    "es5-shim": "^4.5.8",
    "es6-promise": "^3.2.1",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "0.17.2",
    "open-browser-webpack-plugin": "0.0.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "style-loader": "~0.13.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "1.x",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  },
  "author": "dwj",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

No compile errors, the project started normally. But the page can not be displayed normally.

[image]

Comment: I can see the problem. When you do `--hot`, you call the `HotModuleReplacementPlugin` which, from the looks of your `package.json`, isn't initialized. When you do `hot: true`, it doesn't initialize it; remove that line and then fire up the server again with `--hot`.

Comment: just remove --hot ? I tried it just now。 "start": "webpack-dev-server react/main.js --devtool eval --progress --inline --colors --content-base webapp/build",

Comment: The page is still blank.:(

Comment: No, no. In the code bit under `module.exports`, there is a property which says `hot: true`, remove that. Add `--hot` and `--inline` in the `start` script.

Comment: There is no change.:(  I removed hot: true in  webpack.config.js ,but no change. and I removed hot:true and inline: true  .The page is still blank。 I cleaned up browser cache，and project  cache.

Comment: Alright. Try this: with the modifications, run `webpack-dev-server --inline --hot` and paste the output?